# Invalid location of tag a

Tags: html, xhtml

I've a small phtml file:

```html
<nav>
    <a href="/index">Home</a>
    <a href="/help">Hilfe</a>
</nav>
```

Eclise says "Invalid location of tag (a)". But why?

Comment: Did you try `<a href="index">Home</a>` without the slash?

Answer (score 2):

Tipically it is expected the `nav` to contain an `<ul><li>` list of links as documented here http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-nav-element

Comment: Thank's a lot! I tried with dl/dt and it works after starting the validator manually. I tried this before I post this, but it seems, that the validator didn't recognized the changes. Now it seems good!

Comment: It's ok! Using html5 list tags it functions as well